# Convert update statement, to where value is in an array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I am trying to convert an long update script, to a procedure that loops through an array and changes when nececary

OLD Script:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Location_Name_Routine is

BEGIN
    DELETE
        FROM Location
        WHERE Name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z"]%';
  update Location
      set Name = nls_initcap(Name, 'NLS_SORT=xDutch');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' En',' en');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' Van',' van');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' De',' de');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' Den',' den');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' Over',' over');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' Aan',' aan');   
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,' Bij',' bij');
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name,'''S', '''s');
END;
/
```

Must become something like:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
   type array_t is varray(7) of varchar2(10);
   array array_t := array_t(' De', ' Van', ' Den',' Over', ' Aan', ' Bij','''S' );
begin
   for i in 1..array.count loop
    UPDATE Location
        SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, array_t , lower(array_t));
    end loop;
end;
```

In some way it just don't work, no matter what i try.
So if somebody has some sugestions, please just tell them and i will try them right away.

Comment: Is the array fixed in size, and those strings constant? If so, I'd replace all that with a single UPDATE statement - it'll do far less work and be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement:

```
DELETE
    FROM Location
    WHERE Name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z"]%';
```

Has at least two problems. The first is that you are using SQL Server conventions for the `like` pattern, instead of Oracle conventions. You should replace this with a regular expression:

```
DELETE FROM LOCATION
    WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '[^0-9A-Za-z'']');
```

Then, I don't work with arrays much in PL/SQL, but I think you need an index:

```
UPDATE Location
    SET  Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, array_t(i), lower(array_t(i)));
end loop;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your fast respone,
Oracle is complains that:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ARRAY_T": invalid identifier
So i've changed it to 'Array" and it's working now (:.

But what do you mean with the regular expression?

Comment: Thankyou,

I've got another question about that,mabye you can help me?
the apostrophe (') is a character that is ALLOWED in the collumn so can't be deleted.

Comment: You represent an apostrophe in a string by doubling it up.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support regular expressions in a `LIKE` comparison. As @GordonLinoff said, you need to use `DELETE FROM LOCATION WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '[^0-9A-Za-z'']')` in order to compare using a regular expression. Share and enjoy.